# "QueryFailedError: invalid input syntax for integer:" when querying on type float

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

When querying the database using the TypeORM QueryBuilder() I get:

```
QueryFailedError: invalid input syntax for integer: "X"
```

With X being the value stored in the DB.

Originally my entity was of type;

```
{type: 'decimal', precision: 5, scale: 2 }
value: number
```

Since I have changed it to:

```
{type: 'real'}
value: string
```

and tried:

```
'float'
value: string
```

All three types throw the same error. However, if the value in the DB doesn't have any decimal places - it works fine.

I am running Postgres v11.4, TypeORM v0.2.18 and Nest.js v6.5.3

The entity definition:

```
export class Entity extends BaseEntity {

    @Column('float')
    value: string;
}
```

The query:

```
const current = await this.entityRepo
            .createQueryBuilder('uL')
            .leftJoin('uL.user', 'user')
            .leftJoinAndSelect('uL.currentLevel', 'cL')
            .where('user.id = :id', { id: userId })
            .getOne();
```

I am expecting the entity to be returned with the value being of correct decimal spacing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I faced the same error, after updating to *TypeORM v0.2.18*: PostgreSQL doesn't actually know "number"; more on that in the *typeorm* repository on *Microsoft* [GitHub](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/driver/types/ColumnTypes.ts#L37)

Changed this:

```js
@Column()
value: number;
```

... to that:

```js
@Column({type: 'real'})
value: string;
```

*I forgot to migrate; did you?*

**Important** Run a migration, to actually apply these changes:

```sh
npm run typeorm:migrate ChangedNumbersTypeToReal
npm run build; npm run typeorm:run
```

Everything should be well now.

You can read more about migrations with TypeORM on their [GitHub](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/migrations.md)

Comment: Thanks, it helped me, the only observation is that here I had to clean up the changed column before running the migration